# Excel - Offset to last non-blank cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

From my research, when a bunch of cells are merged, you can only reference the first row and first column of the merged cells. EG. if A1:A3 are merged, then I can only access the data using A1 only, and A2 and A3 returns 0.

Now let's say I have a column B that has a formula that calculates based on values in column A. If I drag this formula down, then B2 and B3 will end up using value of 0, when they should be using value in A1.

Effectively, what i want to do is "if the cell in column A (of this row) is blank, then use the last non-blank value going upwards".

I know this will need to combine a couple of formulas, but I can't figure out how to create this. For a start, I can use the Offset function to "go up", but the difficult part here is how to find the previous non-blank cell?

I also tried combing OFFSET with COUNTA (see https://www.exceltip.com/other-qa-formulas/get-the-value-of-the-last-non-blank-cell-in-a-column-in-microsoft-excel.html), but this doesn't work if this occurs multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the helper column, you can use the `INDEX` + `AGGREGATE` functions:

```
=INDEX($A$1:A1,AGGREGATE(14,6,($A$1:A1<>"")*ROW($A$1:A1),1))
```

[image]

Comment: Does this work when row 1 is a header row? I think the INDEX won't return the correct row in this case. But since I now have the row number, i can use INDIRECT to get the right row.

Comment: Yes, i think this works. But i just want to see if i can simplify the formula a bit. Is it possible to get rid of the AGGREGATE, and just use MAX?

Comment: Yes, you can, but then you need enter that formula as array formula with ```ctrl``` + ```shift``` + ```enter```. And you don't need to use ```INDIRECT```, just change range to $A$2:A2 if you have header row.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to use a helper column:

[image]

In B2 write

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A2)),0,B1+1)
```

and in C2 write

```
=OFFSET(A2,-B2,0)
```

Edit: actually... the solution without helper column is even easier! Write in B2:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),B1,A2)
```

[image]

Comment: I like how simple this one is so kudos for that, but i would prefer to have a solution that does not need helper columns.

Comment: See my edit... just use `=IF(ISBLANK(A2),B1,A2)` in B2